# Count the specific text in cell in Tableau

Tags: count, tableau-api, countif

I have a data in a column where People have mentioned the country name where they have traveled

Data will be like this

[click here to see how data will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fZUi.png)

I want the count for each country in one Table(see below). How can I do that?

[click here to how i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVpPs.png)

Comment: Analysis will be easier if you factor your data into at least third Normal form, I.e. don’t cram multiple values into one cell

Comment: Thanks But I am getting data Like that. Now, whats the solution?

Comment: We all get data like that. My point is that you’ll be able to perform analysis and visualization more effectively (and easily) if you invest time to clean and normalize your data first. If this is a recurring task, you can automate the reshaping task.

Comment: I agree. What I was looking for is that if there is any formula I can use . Anyways Thanks very Much